# Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, wcf, authentication

My webservices throw the error `Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services` when I try to access them when I'm signed in to my site (using Forms authentication).

I require:

- service has to work over http and https
- service has to work whether I'm logged in or not
- service has to work cross-domain

The services currently work over http, https and when I'm not logged in, also cross-domain.

I was checking these posts:

1. [Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services. AJAX query to WCF service via SSL proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978380/cross-domain-javascript-callback-is-not-supported-in-authenticated-services-aja)
2. [WCF REST Service Template 40(CS) Cross domain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889599/wcf-rest-service-template-40cs-cross-domain-error/26282069?noredirect=1#comment42210551_26282069)

I've implemented the code from the later:

**global.asax**

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  If HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim domainname As String
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers("Origin")) Then
                domainname = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers("Origin").ToString
                If IsAllowedDomain(domainname) Then
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", domainname)
                End If
                Dim allowedmethods As String = "POST, PUT, DELETE, GET"
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers")) Then
                    Dim headers As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers").ToString()
                    Dim accesscontrolmaxage As String = "1728000"
                    Dim contenttypeforoptionsrequest As String = "application/json"
                    If HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod = "OPTIONS" Then
                        // 'These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", allowedmethods)
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers)
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", accesscontrolmaxage)
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("ContentType", contenttypeforoptionsrequest)
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
End Sub     


Private Function IsAllowedDomain(ByVal Domain As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Domain) Then
        Return False
    End If
    Dim alloweddomains As String() = {"http://www.example.com/", "https://www.example.com/" _
                    , "http://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com"}

    //' you can place comma separated domains here.
    For Each alloweddomain As String In alloweddomains
        If Domain.ToLower() = alloweddomain.ToLower() Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

However, I still get the error `Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services`.

Here's the trace, now sure which part is relevant, and I was unable to find an XML beautifier that creates better readable code from partial XML (and I'm on my max post length on SO):

```
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>458758</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.0932946Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{7eaf0c72-3964-4958-ba6a-2d50b59f55d3}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityImpersonationSuccess.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Security Impersonation succeeded at the server.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/SecurityImpersonationTraceRecord"><OperationAction>http://tempuri.org/Iweddingservice/getShopItems</OperationAction><OperationName>getShopItems</OperationName></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.0932946Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{7eaf0c72-3964-4958-ba6a-2d50b59f55d3}" RelatedActivityID="{cfb5bfd4-41eb-48d8-9607-fecc98c568c9}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Suspend">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.0932946Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{7eaf0c72-3964-4958-ba6a-2d50b59f55d3}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Suspend"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Process action ''.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ProcessAction</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Start">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.0932946Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{cfb5bfd4-41eb-48d8-9607-fecc98c568c9}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Start"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Execute 'RestService.Iweddingservice.getShopItems'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ExecuteUserCode</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.1355943Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{cfb5bfd4-41eb-48d8-9607-fecc98c568c9}" RelatedActivityID="{7eaf0c72-3964-4958-ba6a-2d50b59f55d3}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Stop">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.1355943Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{cfb5bfd4-41eb-48d8-9607-fecc98c568c9}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Stop"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Execute 'RestService.Iweddingservice.getShopItems'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ExecuteUserCode</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Resume">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.1355943Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{7eaf0c72-3964-4958-ba6a-2d50b59f55d3}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Resume"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Process action ''.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ProcessAction</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262164</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.1596037Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{7eaf0c72-3964-4958-ba6a-2d50b59f55d3}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Sent a message over a channel.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext+HostedRequestHttpOutput/24339230</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord"><MessageProperties><Encoder>ByteStreamMessageEncoder</Encoder><AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching></MessageProperties><MessageHeaders></MessageHeaders></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Stop">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T01:59:27.1615922Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{7eaf0c72-3964-4958-ba6a-2d50b59f55d3}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Stop"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Process action ''.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ProcessAction</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262168</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7262153Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{9b143ba2-aa47-413b-bd29-3dff3da3d4db}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectToIPEndpoint.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Connection information.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager/43502130</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><LocalEndpoint>10.0.0.37:80</LocalEndpoint><RemoteEndpoint>10.0.0.37:64203</RemoteEndpoint></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7262153Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{9b143ba2-aa47-413b-bd29-3dff3da3d4db}" RelatedActivityID="{dd5a6292-8955-4616-a0a3-5b88ae8d2e0a}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Start">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7262153Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{dd5a6292-8955-4616-a0a3-5b88ae8d2e0a}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Start"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Activity boundary.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Process action ''.</ActivityName><ActivityType>ProcessAction</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262163</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7262153Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{dd5a6292-8955-4616-a0a3-5b88ae8d2e0a}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageReceived.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Received a message over a channel.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext+HostedHttpInput/2666667</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTransmitTraceRecord"><MessageProperties><AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching><Via>http://flo/weddingservice.svc/getshopitems/?newurl=http://www.nl/trouwshop/bedankdoosjes</Via></MessageProperties><MessageHeaders><To d4p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://flo/weddingservice.svc/getshopitems/?newurl=http://www.nl/trouwshop/bedankdoosjes</To></MessageHeaders></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262163</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7262153Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{9b143ba2-aa47-413b-bd29-3dff3da3d4db}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageReceived.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Received a message over a channel.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor/9642931</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTransmitTraceRecord"><MessageProperties><AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching><Via>http://flo/weddingservice.svc/getshopitems/?newurl=http://www.nl/trouwshop/bedankdoosjes</Via></MessageProperties><MessageHeaders><To d4p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://flo/weddingservice.svc/getshopitems/?newurl=http://www.nl/trouwshop/bedankdoosjes</To></MessageHeaders></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>983077</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7262153Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{dd5a6292-8955-4616-a0a3-5b88ae8d2e0a}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/.WebRequestMatchesOperation.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Incoming HTTP request to URI 'http://flo/weddingservice.svc/getshopitems/?newurl=http://www.nl/trouwshop/bedankdoosjes' matched operation 'getShopItems'.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><Source>System.String/33588939</Source></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131075</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7272158Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{dd5a6292-8955-4616-a0a3-5b88ae8d2e0a}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Throwing an exception.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NotSupportedException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.JavascriptCallbackMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(Message&amp;amp; request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.AfterReceiveRequestCore(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass4.&amp;lt;CallbackGenerator&amp;gt;b__2(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
       at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
       at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
       at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
       at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
       at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
       at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
       at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
    </StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NotSupportedException: Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services.</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131076</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7292163Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{dd5a6292-8955-4616-a0a3-5b88ae8d2e0a}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord Severity="Error" Channel="Operational" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Handling an exception. Exception details: System.NotSupportedException: Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services.
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.JavascriptCallbackMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(Message&amp; request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.AfterReceiveRequestCore(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NotSupportedException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.JavascriptCallbackMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(Message&amp;amp; request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.AfterReceiveRequestCore(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NotSupportedException: Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services.
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.JavascriptCallbackMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(Message&amp;amp; request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.AfterReceiveRequestCore(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262164</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7302173Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{dd5a6292-8955-4616-a0a3-5b88ae8d2e0a}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-NL/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Sent a message over a channel.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-5-130599719510527924</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext+HostedRequestHttpOutput/61789146</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord"><MessageProperties><Encoder>ByteStreamMessageEncoder</Encoder><AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching></MessageProperties><MessageHeaders></MessageHeaders></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Stop">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-11-09T02:02:15.7302173Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{dd5a6292-8955-4616-a0a3-5b88ae8d2e0a}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="5860" ThreadID="36" /><Channel/><Computer>FLO</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><Dat
```

Comment: Read this - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/634bb3b1-8396-4dee-8247-1fb2649c9af1/wcf-4-and-jsonp-and-aspnetcompatibilityenabled?forum=wcf, http://forums.asp.net/t/1613902.aspx?Cross+domain+javascript+callback+is+not+supported+in+authenticated+services+ ,http://jeremybranham.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/authenticated-wcf-service-that-returns-jsonp/  Are you using `jsonp` in javascript to invoke `WCF`

Comment: Ok, after reading that:
1. I need support to call my services from other domains, so I guess that makes the property `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"` required?
2. because I'm calling the services cross-domain I need jsonp?
3. with jsonp I always need to provide a callback url? Because I altered my current service's datatype from `json` to `jsonp` and now suddenly a `callback` parameter is added to my requests.

Comment: when you use `jsonp`, it will automatically append `callback` param, and `jsonp` is meant for cross domain only. So when you use `authenticated wcf` call, and used `jsonp`, then either you need to set `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` = `false`, or don't use `jsonp` at all, or change `forms authentication` to some other say `oAuth` or something other.

Comment: But without jsonp I can't do authenticated cross-domain calls?

Comment: If you can create a MCVE example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and drop that (http://pastebin.com/), that will very helpful for me to start with  debugging this for you.

Comment: Ok, that will take me some time, but I'll start putting something together. Your offer is very much appreciated!

Comment: I am not able to attach `DB` ( i have `11.0.3000`, where as yours `12.0.2000`), so i am not able to work with the solution given, But roughly looking at the code, i have suggestion - you should not mix `wcf service` code with `MVC` or `web form` , you should have separate solution for `wcf service`, and main purpose of `service based app` is to enable  consumption of `service` via multiple app, so if you separate that, i don't think you will face issue with `wcf invoke with authentication`.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Express, it's free, so maybe you could try that?
Are you saying I should create a stand-alone solution for just my service? Would that be project type 'WCF Service Application'?

Comment: I have a constraint, and i can't upgrade to `sql server 2014`, i think you had used this , whereas i am using `2012`. But yes, i was suggesting to move `wcf` service to separate project and it can be `WCF Service Application` too!

Comment: Alright, I'll try that :) And yes, I was using 2014.